# H2 database throws org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException

Tags: java, sql, oracle, h2

we get below error when using h2,MODE=Oracle. same query works fine with oracle db .
we use h2 db in tests so we want the same sql to fit with both oracle and h2 .

> ```
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type:
> \"OBJECT_KEY\"; SQL statement:\nMERGE INTO TEST_OBJECTS obj USING
> (select ? as OBJECT_KEY, ? as OBJECT_VALUE, ? as ETAG, ? as
> CREATED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP as CREATION_DATE, ? as LAST_UPDATED_BY,
> SYSTIMESTAMP as LAST_UPDATE_DATE from dual) tmp ON (obj.OBJECT_KEY =
> tmp.OBJECT_KEY) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
> obj.OBJECT_VALUE=tmp.OBJECT_VALUE, obj.TAG=tmp.TAG,
> obj.LAST_UPDATED_BY=tmp.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
> obj.LAST_UPDATE_DATE=SYSTIMESTAMP WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
> (OBJECT_KEY, OBJECT_VALUE, TAG, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE,
> LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_DATE) VALUES (tmp.OBJECT_KEY,
> tmp.OBJECT_VALUE, tmp.TAG ,tmp.CREATED_BY, tmp.CREATION_DATE,
> tmp.LAST_UPDATED_BY, tmp.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
> ```

**Query**

> ```
> MERGE INTO TEST_OBJECTS obj USING (select ? as OBJECT_KEY, ? as
> OBJECT_VALUE, ? as TAG, ? as CREATED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP as
> CREATION_DATE, ? as LAST_UPDATED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP as LAST_UPDATE_DATE
> from dual) tmp ON (obj.OBJECT_KEY = tmp.OBJECT_KEY) WHEN MATCHED THEN
> UPDATE SET obj.OBJECT_VALUE=tmp.OBJECT_VALUE,
> obj.TAG=tmp.TAG,obj.LAST_UPDATED_BY=tmp.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
> obj.LAST_UPDATE_DATE=SYSTIMESTAMP WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
> (OBJECT_KEY, OBJECT_VALUE, TAG, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE,
> LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_DATE)VALUES (tmp.OBJECT_KEY,
> tmp.OBJECT_VALUE, tmp.TAG ,tmp.CREATED_BY,tmp.CREATION_DATE,
> tmp.LAST_UPDATED_BY, tmp.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

H2 compiles prepared statements immediately before parameters are set, but this command needs to know their data types to create a derived table. The usual workaround is to wrap parameters with cast specifications:

```sql
(select (CAST ? AS dataType1) as OBJECT_KEY,
CAST(? AS dataType2) as OBJECT_VALUE,
CAST(? AS dataType3) as ETAG,
CAST(? AS dataType4) as CREATED_BY,
SYSTIMESTAMP as CREATION_DATE,
CAST(? AS dataType5) as LAST_UPDATED_BY,
SYSTIMESTAMP as LAST_UPDATE_DATE from dual)
```

Use real data type names instead of `dataType*`, you can take them from definitions of related columns in the `TEST_OBJECTS` table.

Comment: cast is not working in oracle with blob